# How can I set rejectUnauthorized=false in psql command line when connect to postgresql server?

Tags: postgresql

In my nodejs program, I am using

```
ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
          },
```

as the connect option to connect to Postgresql server.

When I use command line, it rejects my connection with below error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "user"
FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "123.208.189.86", user "user", database "test", SSL off
```

I wonder how I can set this option via `psql` command line?

I have tried different options:

```
sslmode=verify-full
sslmode=verify-ca
sslmode=diabled
sslmode=prefer
sslmode=allow
```

but none of above is working.

Comment: `rejectUnauthorized: false` turns off a node feature which does not exist in psql, so it has no direct equivalent.  What problem are you trying to solve?  What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: I am getting an error `PAM authentication failed for user` when connect to RDS postgresql

Comment: That sounds like a password or access token error, not an ssl error which would be relevant to rejectUnauthorized